# Java GridBagConstraints

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I have 5 components in a JPanel.
Everything is looking smooth with the first 4 component's I've added.
However, when I try adding a 5th component to the JPanel, the spacing between the components change for whatever reason!

Without 5th component:

```
First Name: [..............]

Last Name: [..............]
```

With:

```
First Name:---------------- [.............]

Last Name:----------------- [.............]

What is your favorite sport:
```

Pretend the dashes above between label and textfield is space

The spacing between the labels and textfield change!
Here is my code, please help me!

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Survey");
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    //LINE.START = Top Left Corner
    frame.add(p1);

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 10, 10);

    JLabel lblFirstN = new JLabel("First Name:");
    JLabel lblLastN = new JLabel("Last Name:");
    JLabel lblFavSport = new JLabel("What is your favorite sport:");

    JTextField txtFirstN = new JTextField();
    txtFirstN.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));

    JTextField txtLastN = new JTextField();
    txtLastN.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    p1.add(lblFirstN, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    p1.add(txtFirstN, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    p1.add(lblLastN, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    p1.add(txtLastN, gbc);

    //this block of code is what is screwing me
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    p1.add(lblFavSport, gbc);
}
```

Comment: Please, can someone respond.

Comment: What is the question? Are you trying to align the bottom label with the others?

Comment: I just found out that if I decrease the amount of text of the JLabel, the problem with the spacing goes away. So yes, I'm trying to align the bottom label with the others but it's causing a spacing problem if the text is too long and in this case "What is your favorite sport" is too long.......... that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why it's doing this, please?

Comment: Take a look at gridwidth. If you use it with a value of 2 for the last label, it will low the textfields to over lap it's grid position

Comment: @MadProgrammer Wow thanks for the answer! It seems that the more text the last label is, the more I have to increase gridwith. Can you please explain that in a little more detail why I have to do that?

Comment: `Please, can someone respond.` What? It was 8 minutes since you posted your question! Did you read any tutorials while you were waiting? People answer questions when then have the time and know the answer. Instead of asking why why why, do some basic reading and ask for a link to a tutorial instead. The GridBagLayout tutorial that is part of the Swing tutorial is very detail and explains how the constraints work. So start by reading the tutorial.

Comment: Think about the name "Grid". GridBagLayout uses a grid to layout it's components. What's happened is when you've added the last label, the size of the column has increased, so the components in the column have had there cells width increased. This is how GridBagLayout works

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of 2 columns layout (ie, all labels are aligned and all their corresponding widgets/fields are aligned, vertically)? Or do you wan to get rid of the space between the labels and their widgets/fields? In the first case, GBL is your friend, else consider wrapping each label/field into sub-panels

Answer (score 3):

The reason your getting this output is because, that's the way the layout manager is designed.

`GridBagLayout` is a (virtual) extension of the `GridLayout`.  In the fact that it lays it's components out in a grid, but is far more flexible then the `GridLayout`.  It is the closes you will get to something like a HTML table in the included layout managers.

Lets take closer look.  The following code...

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
add(new JLabel("First Name"), gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
add(new JLabel("Last Name"), gbc);

gbc.gridx = 1;
gbc.gridy = 0;
add(new JTextField(15), gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
add(new JTextField(15), gbc);
```

Generates

[image]

Clearly, you can see the rows and columns.  Each row has the same height and each column has the same width...

Now, if we add the next label and field...

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
add(new JLabel("First Name"), gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
add(new JLabel("Last Name"), gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
add(new JLabel("What is your favorite sport:"), gbc);

gbc.gridx = 1;
gbc.gridy = 0;
add(new JTextField(15), gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
add(new JTextField(15), gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
add(new JTextField(15), gbc);
```

And here is your current problem...

[image]

You can see that the first column's width has increased to accommodate the new label...

Now we can fix this by using `gridWidth`...

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
add(new JLabel("First Name"), gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
add(new JLabel("Last Name"), gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
gbc.gridwidth = 2;
add(new JLabel("What is your favorite sport:"), gbc);

gbc.gridwidth = 1;
gbc.gridx = 1;
gbc.gridy = 0;
add(new JTextField(15), gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
add(new JTextField(15), gbc);
gbc.gridx = 2;
gbc.gridy++;
add(new JTextField(15), gbc);
```

*nb: The last fields `gridx` position has had to be increased, other wise it would actually sit over the label!*

[image]

Now, that's better, but, I don't think that's quite what you want :P

We need to adjust the first two fields to span into the next cell as well...

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
add(new JLabel("First Name"), gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
add(new JLabel("Last Name"), gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
gbc.gridwidth = 2;
add(new JLabel("What is your favorite sport:"), gbc);

gbc.gridwidth = 2;
gbc.gridx = 1;
gbc.gridy = 0;
add(new JTextField(15), gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
add(new JTextField(15), gbc);
gbc.gridx = 2;
gbc.gridy++;
add(new JTextField(15), gbc);
```

[image]

Finally :P - Simple as pie :D

You may want to take a closer look at [How to use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details...

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the last `JLabel` is not aligned with the previous 2 is that all labels are center aligned and appear in the same column. When there are only 2 labels, they appear aligned due to the happy coincidence that their `FontMetric` widths are equal. Add a third and the labels appear staggered.

To fix, you can anchor the labels to counter this effect by anchoring the components to `GridBagConstraints.WEST` and set the weight along the x axis:

```
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
```

This has the effect of left aligning component within their `GridBagLayout` "cells".