# Need Help, Java GUI in Eclipse

Tags: java, swing

I'm using GridBagLayout for my app because i think it's easier to set the component's position. but i have the problem with the width. Look at the OK Button

[image: Look at the OK Button]

and the code:

```
public LoginForm1 (){
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,0));
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    this.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);

    JPanel MainPanel = new JPanel();    
    getContentPane().add(MainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    GridBagLayout GridPanel = new GridBagLayout();
    GridPanel.columnWidths = new int[] {0,0,0,0};
    GridPanel.rowHeights = new int[] {0,0,0,0,0};
    GridPanel.columnWeights = new double[] {0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0};
    GridPanel.rowWeights = new double[] {1.0, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0, 0.1};
    MainPanel.setLayout(GridPanel);

    JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Username : ");
    userLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
    GridBagConstraints userLabelGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
    userLabelGrid.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    userLabelGrid.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    userLabelGrid.gridx = 1;
    userLabelGrid.gridy = 1;
    MainPanel.add(userLabel, userLabelGrid);

    JLabel passLabel = new JLabel("Password : ");
    passLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
    GridBagConstraints passLabelGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
    passLabelGrid.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    passLabelGrid.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    passLabelGrid.gridx = 1;
    passLabelGrid.gridy = 2;
    MainPanel.add(passLabel, passLabelGrid);

    JTextField userField = new JTextField();
    userField.setFont(UIManager.getFont("TextField.font"));
    GridBagConstraints userFieldGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
    userFieldGrid.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    userFieldGrid.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 0);
    userFieldGrid.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    userFieldGrid.gridx = 2;
    userFieldGrid.gridy = 1;
    userField.setColumns(30);
    MainPanel.add(userField, userFieldGrid);

    JTextField passField = new JTextField();
    passField.setFont(UIManager.getFont("PasswordField.font"));
    GridBagConstraints passFieldGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
    passFieldGrid.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    passFieldGrid.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 0);
    passFieldGrid.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    passFieldGrid.gridx = 2;
    passFieldGrid.gridy = 2;
    passField.setColumns(30);
    MainPanel.add(passField, passFieldGrid);

    JButton okButton = new JButton();
    GridBagConstraints okButtonGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
    okButtonGrid.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    okButtonGrid.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 0);
    okButtonGrid.gridx = 1;
    okButtonGrid.gridy = 4;
    okButton.setText("OK");
    MainPanel.add(okButton, okButtonGrid);

    JButton cancelButton = new JButton();
    GridBagConstraints cancelButtonGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
    cancelButtonGrid.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    cancelButtonGrid.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
    cancelButtonGrid.gridx = 2;
    cancelButtonGrid.gridy = 4;
    cancelButton.setText("CANCEL");
    MainPanel.add(cancelButton, cancelButtonGrid);
}
```

What am i missing?? Please Help, Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you haven't told us what's wrong with the button.

Comment: So how do you want the buttons to look?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980712/java-gridbagconstraints/15982748#15982748) for some info on how `GridBagLayout` works

Comment: Please, spend 15 minute readying this guide: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 2):

You could remove the `.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH` for both the buttons, that would stop the buttons from wanting to expand to fill the full width (and height) of the cells...

[image]

I'd also take a look at your `GridPanel.columnWeights` and `GridPanel.rowWeights` to ensure that they meet your needs...

Because of the nature of `GridBagLayout`, you'd actually be better using a series of panels to layout in individual elements (fields and buttons) seperatly, this will give you better control over the layout...

[image]

```
public class LoginPane extends JPanel {

    public LoginPane() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

        add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Username : ");

        userLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        GridBagConstraints userLabelGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
        userLabelGrid.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        userLabelGrid.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        userLabelGrid.gridx = 1;
        userLabelGrid.gridy = 1;

        mainPanel.add(userLabel, userLabelGrid);
        JLabel passLabel = new JLabel("Password : ");

        passLabel.setFont(
                        new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        GridBagConstraints passLabelGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
        passLabelGrid.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        passLabelGrid.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        passLabelGrid.gridx = 1;
        passLabelGrid.gridy = 2;

        mainPanel.add(passLabel, passLabelGrid);
        JTextField userField = new JTextField();

        userField.setFont(UIManager.getFont("TextField.font"));
        GridBagConstraints userFieldGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
        userFieldGrid.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        userFieldGrid.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 0);
        userFieldGrid.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        userFieldGrid.gridx = 2;
        userFieldGrid.gridy = 1;

        userField.setColumns(
                        30);
        mainPanel.add(userField, userFieldGrid);
        JTextField passField = new JTextField();

        passField.setFont(UIManager.getFont("PasswordField.font"));
        GridBagConstraints passFieldGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
        passFieldGrid.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        passFieldGrid.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 0);
        passFieldGrid.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        passFieldGrid.gridx = 2;
        passFieldGrid.gridy = 2;

        passField.setColumns(30);
        mainPanel.add(passField, passFieldGrid);
        JButton okButton = new JButton();

        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints okButtonGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
        okButtonGrid.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 0);
        okButtonGrid.gridx = 0;
        okButtonGrid.gridy = 0;

        okButton.setText("OK");
        buttonPane.add(okButton, okButtonGrid);

        JButton cancelButton = new JButton();
        GridBagConstraints cancelButtonGrid = new GridBagConstraints();
        cancelButtonGrid.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
        cancelButtonGrid.gridx = 1;
        cancelButtonGrid.gridy = 0;

        cancelButton.setText("CANCEL");
        buttonPane.add(cancelButton, cancelButtonGrid);

        add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }
}
```

**ps**

*"Look at the OK Button"* means nothing...The buttons are laid out exactly as you have stated that they should be...

Comment: Thanks for the response.. i mean the 2 buttons don't have a same width.. the "cancel" button is longer than "ok" ..

Comment: There are multiple levels of issues. The first being with the way you have everything laied out start with, even when the buttons are the same size, they won't be centered. To over come this, use the second example and add a .fill = HORIZONTAL and if required, .weightx = 1

Answer (score 0):

```
 cancelButtonGrid.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
```

the [GridBagConstraints.BOTH](http://dsearls.org/courses/C113Java/QuickReference/GridBagLayout.htm) will stretch the component horizontally and vertically to fill the entire width and the entire height of its cell

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, the problem is, the buttons at the bottom of the screen are to wide

Comment: aha , sorry i didn't see that , i thought the broblem in the JFrame width , sorrrrrrrrry for that :(