# GridBagConstraints for Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, gridbaglayout

Here is some Java Code that I have that works that uses GridBagConstraints:

```
public AuctionClient() {
    JFrame guiFrame = new JFrame();
    JPanel guiPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JLabel userNameLabel = new JLabel("UserName:");
    JTextField userNameTextField = new JTextField(30);
    JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    JButton registerButton = new JButton("Register");                

    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
    JTextField passwordTextField = new JPasswordField(30);

    guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    guiFrame.setTitle("Auction Client");
    guiFrame.setSize(500, 250);

    guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    GridBagConstraints labelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    labelGBC.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
    GridBagConstraints fieldGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    fieldGBC.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
    fieldGBC.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    guiPanel.add(userNameLabel, labelGBC);
    guiPanel.add(userNameTextField, fieldGBC);

    guiPanel.add(passwordLabel, labelGBC);
    guiPanel.add(passwordTextField, fieldGBC);    

    GridBagConstraints loginButtonGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    loginButtonGBC.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);        
    GridBagConstraints registerButtonGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    registerButtonGBC.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);        
    registerButtonGBC.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    guiPanel.add(loginButton, loginButtonGBC);                        
    guiPanel.add(registerButton, registerButtonGBC);                                

    guiFrame.add(guiPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    guiFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I have had a look online for some explanation of how the GridBagConstraints work in relation to placing controls on a panel. I could not understand exactly how it works so am asking a question here on this forum.

Here is a screenshot of the above code when running:

[image]

Can I please have some help to position the Login and Register buttons in the middle of the panel, side by side.

**EDIT**

Here is my current working code:

```
    public AuctionClientLogon() {
    JFrame guiFrame = new JFrame();
    JPanel guiFieldsPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JPanel guiButtonsPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());        
    JLabel userNameLabel = new JLabel("UserName:");
    JTextField userNameTextField = new JTextField(30);
    JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    JButton registerButton = new JButton("Register");                

    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
    JTextField passwordTextField = new JPasswordField(30);

    guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    guiFrame.setTitle("Auction Client");
    guiFrame.setSize(500, 250);

    guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();        
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;        

    guiFieldsPanel.add(userNameLabel, gbc);
    gbc.gridx++;
    guiFieldsPanel.add(userNameTextField, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;        
    guiFieldsPanel.add(passwordLabel, gbc);
    gbc.gridx++;        
    guiFieldsPanel.add(passwordTextField, gbc);    

    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;                
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    guiButtonsPanel.add(loginButton, gbc);     
    gbc.gridx++;                
    guiButtonsPanel.add(registerButton, gbc);                                

    guiFrame.add(guiFieldsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    guiFrame.add(guiButtonsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);        
    guiFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Here is an image:

http://canning.co.nz/Java/Positioning_Image2.png

Is it possible to place the Labels and TextFields in the Center as well as the buttons, but not on top of each other? I would like everything in the Center if possible, but the buttons to be a little bit lower than the Labels and TextFields. Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980712/java-gridbagconstraints/15982748#15982748)** to start with and [How to use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Comment: I hope this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11428289/1057230)  too, might will be of interest to you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Start by taking a look at your forms requirements.  You have two sections.  The fields and the buttons.  Each of these sections have a (slightly) different layout requirement.

Start by separating the layout to best meet these requirements.

Create a `JPanel` to hold the fields and a `JPanel` for the buttons.  These panels could have different layouts if required, but the example I've included uses `GridBagLayout` for each.

Then layout your components accordingly (on there individual panels).

Then bring it all together...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class GridBagLayout01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GridBagLayout01();
    }

    public GridBagLayout01() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame guiFrame = new JFrame();
                JPanel guiPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                JLabel userNameLabel = new JLabel("UserName:");
                JTextField userNameTextField = new JTextField(30);
                JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
                JButton registerButton = new JButton("Register");

                JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
                JTextField passwordTextField = new JPasswordField(30);

                guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                guiFrame.setTitle("Auction Client");
                guiFrame.setSize(500, 250);

                guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

                JPanel fields = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

                GridBagConstraints labelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
                labelGBC.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
                GridBagConstraints fieldGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
                fieldGBC.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
                fieldGBC.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                fields.add(userNameLabel, labelGBC);
                fields.add(userNameTextField, fieldGBC);

                fields.add(passwordLabel, labelGBC);
                fields.add(passwordTextField, fieldGBC);

                JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

                GridBagConstraints loginButtonGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
                loginButtonGBC.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
                GridBagConstraints registerButtonGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
                registerButtonGBC.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
                registerButtonGBC.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                buttons.add(loginButton, loginButtonGBC);
                buttons.add(registerButton, registerButtonGBC);

                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                guiPanel.add(fields, gbc);
                guiPanel.add(buttons, gbc);

                guiFrame.add(guiPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                guiFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a FlowLayout to keep this kind of line of buttons.Then you can easily place the button position where ever you want inline.
 Have a look at [how to use flow layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html)